# Get the leaf value of json object by key.key in string

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, replace, key

I am trying to replace a template by a JSON object in typescript. I wanna get the value from JSON Object by something like `data['customer.name']` but I don't know how to do that. For detail:

Here is my template

```
Dear {customer.name},
Congratulations on winning a valuable prize {award.prize},
...
```

And my data is:

```
let data = {
  "customer":{
    "name": "Allen Wade"
  },
  "award":{
    "prize": "$100.00"
  }
}
```

So how can i get a customer name by something like `data['customer.name']` to replace my template.

Thank you!

Comment: Adriano Spadoni's answer to the duplicate is probably the  best